# Add only dependencies of a library, not itself in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Assume there is a library:

`com.onesignal.onesignal`

It has a few dependencies itself (In its pom file).

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1'
'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1'
'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
```

Is there any way to **add all the dependencies in the pom file, but not the library itself**??

So I'm having all the libraries in my classpath, but the first package is not included in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add all the libraries as they are, but spare the one you do not want? This way you need 7 inlcudes (in your example)

or exclude the library you do not want like
`exclude group: 'com.onesignal', module: 'onesignal'`